# Unable to use arguments in datepicker

Tags: android, datepicker, kotlin

How to use the arguments outside the parenthesis.
I am trying to take the inputs from two dates pickers **picker1** and **picker2** and want to subtract the dates.here is my code

```
package com.rohithsai.simpleintrest

import android.app.DatePickerDialog
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
var formate = SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, YYYY", Locale.US)
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
        var preday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        val premonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val preyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)

    picker1.setOnClickListener() {

        val dpd = DatePickerDialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { datePicker, selyear1, selmonth1, selday1 ->
        }, preyear, premonth, preday)

        //show datepicker
        dpd.show()
    }
    picker2.setOnClickListener() {


        val dpd = DatePickerDialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { datePicker, selyear2,selmonth2, selday2 ->
        }, preyear, premonth, preday)

        //show datepicker
        dpd.show()
    }
     //see here
    //tv1.text="$selday1/$selmonth1/selyear1"

  }
 }
```

i want to access the arguments **selday1 selmonth1 selyear1**
 and **selday2 selmonth2 selyear2** outside the parenthesis.i cant able to use it in the place of **see here** in the code.please help me.correct answers may be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to use them at the place you want to.

**see here** is inside your `onCreate()` method and the values you want to use (**selday1 selmonth1, selyear1, selday2, selmonth2** and **selyear2**) are in defined in separate `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListeners`.

The scopes are different and the OnDateSetListeners will be triggered way after onCreate has finished anyway.

It can't work like this, you will have to redesign your code.

Comment: I am afraid that is beyond the scope of your question.